# Header location on submit form php

Tags: php, forms

I am working on a PHP form, and it shows a thank you message while you submit the form.

The problem there is on i can't handle both metods:

Header:

```
header('Location: index.php#5');
```

Sent:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))

{
$success='<h1>Thank you!</h1>';
unset($_SESSION['sent']);
```

}

I tried to make it work with:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))
header('Location: index.php#5'); 
{
$success='<h1>Thank you!</h1>';
unset($_SESSION['sent']);
}
```

But the Thank you! message, is always visible.

SOLVED:

I added the header function on submit.php, not on index.php

Comment: You can't display content and redirect at the same time. Either redirect and display the content, or display the content and use a meta refresh or javascript refresh to redirect after a period of time.

Comment: So I can't make the website scroll back to the original position (after it refresh) and then make the thank you message appear?

Comment: You can but it's a two step process. First redirect and then when the page loads display your message. But that's *two separate* steps.

Comment: Then I should add 2 methods on "sent"? I am not used to work with php, that's why I am a little bit lost

Answer (score 0):

Try this code is right

```
<?php
session_start();
$success = '';

if($_POST){
    //@TODO Handle form post

    $_SESSION['sent'] = true;
    header("Location:index.php");
}


if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))
{
$success='<h1>Thank you!</h1>';
unset($_SESSION['sent']);
}

echo $success;
?>
```

And not use `#` server side dont read this value, use `?` to make GET attributes.

Comment: U mean I can't use the # in the url? because there is the only way to do it since I am using "One Page Scroll" and it works on this way with the URL / Anchors